# iOS - Swipeable UITableCells Without Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm working on a project where I need to use 3 storyboards, one for iPhone 5, the other for iPhone 6, and the last for iPhone 6+. I need to implement Swipeable `UITableCell`s to show more options in this project.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views to semi-successfully get this done, but the problem is that this requires auto layout and manipulating constraints to make the table cells swipeable via a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Is there any way to achieve the same user experience without using constraints? I'm kinda new to `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, so any advice on how to start on this would be wonderful, or if there are any tutorials out that that do the same things without using constraints.

Comment: Thanks dude and hope you find ur problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIPanGestureRecognizer` is used to detect if user have clicked the screen.[Check this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html)

You are using UITableView then you wont need `UIPanGestureRecognizer` . Try using 
AutoLayout And become familyer with it .

Try to check following tutorial for tableview [Create a Simple Table View App](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) , [Customize Table View Cells for UITableView](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) , [How To Handle Row Selection in UITableView](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/)

If you have got problem with auto-layout ask it I would try to help you out

Comment: Very sorry for forgetting! Last week, my codeveloper helped me do this with autolayout. Even though I'm 3 storyboards, xcode finally allowed me to use constraints only on views where I needed them! Thanks again and very sorry!

Comment: Sounds great then you might be enjoying solving autolayout issues

Comment: Haha they are kind of annoying! I change one thing and the whole view breaks! But I've been learning. I only needed constraints for the the swipeable table cells and they work great!

Comment: if u have got problem using auto layout u can post question in here and inform me i would try to help u out